# Ajax + Controller Action in Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I'm new to programming, and I'm trying to call a function when the user inputs data and clicks submit button. I'm using Yii2 and I'm not familiar with Ajax. I tried developing a function, but my controller action isn't called.

Here is the example code I'm trying:

views/index.php:

```
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl. '/supermarkets/sample' ?>',
           type: 'post',
           data: {searchname: $("#searchname").val() , searchby:$("#searchby").val()},
           success: function (data) {
              alert(data);

           }

      });
    }
</script>

<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\LinkPager;

?>
<h1>Supermarkets</h1>
<ul>

<select id="searchby">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Search by</option>
    <option value="Name">Name</option>
    <option value="Location">Location</option>
</select>

<input type="text" value ="" name="searchname", id="searchname">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>
<h3> </h3>
```

Controller:

```
public function actionSample(){         
     echo "ok";
}
```

My problem is that when I click on the Search button nothing happens, and when I try to debug it, the debugger runs no code!

Comment: Check the output using developer tools or firebug. Any errors or error codes?

Comment: There appears to be no errors, but when I clink Search nothing happens.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is sample you can modify according your need

```
public function actionSample()
{
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
    $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
    $searchname= explode(":", $data['searchname']);
    $searchby= explode(":", $data['searchby']);
    $searchname= $searchname[0];
    $searchby= $searchby[0];
    $search = // your logic;
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return [
        'search' => $search,
        'code' => 100,
    ];
  }
}
```

If this will success you will get data in Ajax success block. See browser console.

```
  $.ajax({
       url: '<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl. '/supermarkets/sample' ?>',
       type: 'post',
       data: {
                 searchname: $("#searchname").val() , 
                 searchby:$("#searchby").val() , 
                 _csrf : '<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>'
             },
       success: function (data) {
          console.log(data.search);
       }
  });
```

Comment: I added your code, but the problem is that when I click on Search nothing happens, even while debugging!

Comment: are you inside JavaScript function, myFunction needs to be called.

Comment: I'm calling my function onclick : <button onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>

Comment: you need to verify it

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this, how can I verify it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72148/discussion-between-ankit-and-user3640056).

Comment: There could be some issues with 400 response receiving(_csrf token). I solve by adding (_csrf : '<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>') inside data{ ... }

Comment: Trying your code snippet give me a `SyntaxError: Unexpected string` on the line `url: ... `, any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

you have to pass _csrf tokin as a parameter

```
_csrf: yii.getCsrfToken()
```

or you can disable csrf valdation

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to get the CSRF param is this:

```
data[yii.getCsrfParam()] = yii.getCsrfToken()
```