# Yii2 Ajax Submission not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii2

Iam new to Yii2 and Ajax

I want to add multiple job for a work ,for that I pass id to WorkJobs Controller

This is my code for ajax submission

```
<?php

$this->registerJs(
'$("body").on("beforeSubmit", "form#w1", function() {

    var form = $(this);
    if (form.find(".has-error").length) {
      return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
      var jobid =  "<?php echo $id;?>";

      url: form.attr("work-jobs/create&id="+jobid),
      type: "post",
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function(errors) {
        alert("sdfsdf");
        // How to update form with error messages?
      }
    });

    return false;
    });'
);
 ?>
```

But it's not working ,I don't know what's wrong in my code ,please help ...........

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28832097/2559712

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off [jithin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35765762/393021), make the following changes to your `$.ajax()` call

- Make sure your URL is in quotes. It is a common mistake to forget to quote the URL when interspersing it with PHP. [jithin]

Unlike [jithin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35765762/393021), you should do the following

- instead of responding to the `beforeSubmit` event, handle the `submit` event. This would allow the Yii clientsoide validations do their job
- the `ajax.success` callback takes `data` as the argument; not `error`, there's the `ajax.failure` callback for errors

Answer (score 2):

change your code like below

```
<?php
$url=Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['work-jobs/create','id'=>$id]);
$this->registerJs(
'$("body").on("beforeSubmit", "form#w1", function() {

    var form = $(this);

    if (form.find(".has-error").length) {
      return false;
    }

    $.ajax({


      url: "$url",
      type: "post",
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function(errors) {
        alert("sdfsdf");
        // How to update form with error messages?
      }
    });

    return false;
    });'
);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `createAbsoluteUrl()` in `url` like this:

```
url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl(\"work-jobs/create&id=\")"+jobid
```