# redirect to login page on textarea click?

Tags: php, controller, yii2

i am making a comment form in yii2 and it is working well but i also want the comment textarea to redirect a user that is not logged in to the login page. what i want is onclick of the comment teaxtarea the user get redirected to the login page and after logged in it goes back allowing the user to comment..
 i know if i put a button like

```
 <?= Html::a('up', ['comment'], [ 'class' => 'btn btn-primary' ]) ?>
```

and put it only in the

this is my form

```
  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
       <?= $form->field($comment, 'user_comment')->textarea(['rows' => 4,'columns' => 12]) ?>
<br>
 <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>  
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

this is my controller

```
public function actionBlog()
{ 
      $comment= new Comment();  
 $comment->byy=Yii::$app->user->identity->email;        

    if ($comment->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
        $comment->load($_POST);
    $comment->save();
    return $this->refresh();
       }
    return $this->render('blog',[
        'comment' => $comment,
    ]);
}
```

like i said the controller lets only a logged in user to insert to comment.

Comment: [Refer this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831860/ajax-controller-action-in-yii2)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `JavaScript` and:

1. Add on `onClick` event on the textarea
2. Check if your user is logged, else use `window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";` to redirect

Comment: How do I add on click in yii2 text area form

Comment: It is not redirecting me to the blog page . after login in in it is a taking me to index page